# I have 3 file upload inputs on one page but they are saving the same image extension

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, file-upload

This is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="image_one">1st Product Image:</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image_one" name="image_one" placeholder="image">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="image_two">2nd Product Image:</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image_two" name="image_two" placeholder="image">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="image_three">3rd Product Image:</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="image_three" name="image_three" placeholder="image">
</div>
```

and this is my controller:

```
    if ($request->hasFile('image_one')) {
        $file_one = $request->image_one;
        $extension_one = $file_one->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename_one = time() . '.' . $extension_one;
        $file_one->move('upload/image/', $filename_one);
        $product->image_one = $filename_one;
    }
    

    if ($request->hasFile('image_two')) {
        $file = $request->file('image_two');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('upload/image/', $filename);
        $product->image_two = $filename;
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('image_three')) {
        $file = $request->file('image_three');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('upload/image/', $filename);
        $product->image_three = $filename;
    }
```

It only saves the extension for 1st image i upload in all 3 images database columns.

Can anyone help me to get the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put more info about the insert code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script must be running too quickly making the `time()` function to return the same thing hence the name of the images saved are the same (provided the images have the same extension).

Instead of `time()` use `rand()` for all the three images to generate their random names:

```
$filename = rand() . '.' . $extension;
```

You may also check if the random name does not already exist before you save it.